# How do I plot the 'inverse' of a survival function?

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis

I am trying to plot the inverse of a survival function, as the data I'm is actually an increase in proportion of an event over time. I can produce Kaplan-Meier survival plots, but I want to produce the 'opposite' of these. I can kind of get what I want using the following `fun="cloglog"`:

```
plot(survfit(Surv(Days_until_workers,Workers)~Queen_Number+Treatment,data=xdata),
     fun="cloglog", lty=c(1:4), lwd=2, ylab="Colonies with Workers",
     xlab="Days", las=1, font.lab=2, bty="n")
```

[image: The 'cloglog' function]

But I don't understand quite what this has done to the time (*i.e.* doesn't start at 0 and distance decreases?), and why the survival lines extend above the y axis.

Would really appreciate some help with this!

Cheers

Answer (score 14):

Use `fun="event"` to get the desired output

```
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ x, data = aml)
par(mfrow=1:2, las=1)
plot(fit, col=2:3)
plot(fit, col=2:3, fun="event")
```

[image]

The reason for `fun="cloglog"` screwing up the axes is that it does not plot a fraction at all. It is instead plotting this according to `?plot.survfit`:

> "cloglog" creates a complimentary log-log survival plot (f(y) = log(-log(y)) along with log scale for the x-axis)

Moreover, the `fun` argument is not limited to predefined functions like `"event"` or `"cloglog"`, so you can easily give it your own custom function.

```
plot(fit, col=2:3, fun=function(y) 3*sqrt(1-y))
```